# Finding a constant for a payoff matrix with negative maxmin

Tags: linear-programming, game-theory

From what I understand, when solving a payoff matrix using Linear Programming with a negative $maxmin$ (or $minmax$) you need to supply a constant to add to each element in the payoff matrix. I'm not sure how to choose the constant.

Suppose I have the following payoff matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1 & 0 & -3 \\
6 & -3 & -2 & 0 \\
-3 & -2 & 5 & -3 \\
-4 & 4 & -5 & 5
\end{bmatrix}

This payoff matrix has a $maxmin = -3$ (from rows 1, 2, 3) and $minmax = 4$ (from column 2). I'm inclined to use a constant say $k = 4$ to add to each element of the payoff matrix. My thinking is using $k=4$ will result is a positive value for the resulting $maxmin$ value, which would be $maxmin = 1$.

Is this the correct approach? I believe after I get the resulting value $v$ (and probabilities) of the game I will need to subtract $k$ such that $v^* = v - k$ to obtain the value $v^*$ for the original payoff matrix.

Comment: what is a payoff matrix, and what is the purpose of adding a constant to each element?

Comment: The payoff matrix (just an n x m matrix) is used in Game Theory for two player zero sum games that represents the payoffs from the Row players perspective when a player chooses a particular strategy. A strategy is represented by a row (for Row player), likewise for col. Example, Row player choose row 1 and Column player chooses column 1, Row player would win 4 units. Like if Row player chooses row 3 and Column player chooses column 1, Row player loses 3 units (since the value is negative). Each row and column corresponds to set of strategies. You can mode rock, paper, scissors in this fashion.

Comment: and what is the purpose of adding a constant to each element?

Comment: It's at the top of my question, let me know if that doesn't clear it up.

Comment: What do you mean by "solving a payoff matrix"? In [these slides](https://www.princeton.edu/~rvdb/542/lectures/lec8.pdf) there are a few linlear optimization problems, but none seems to require adding a constant to each element.

Comment: You can solve the payoff matrix by using a linear programming solver, like this one: [link](http://www.phpsimplex.com/simplex/simplex.htm?l=en). You will notice if you input the payoff matrix into the solver as is, you will not find a solution. However if you add 4 to each element it will solve.

Comment: What objective/constraints do I enter? Could you add that to your question?